# Abstract Class Inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class

Somehow, after I define an AbstractClass, I can't have a derived class return an object of the derived class. What is the problem with the following code?

Thanks.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class AbstractClass {
    public:
        virtual AbstractClass<T> operator[](int index) = 0;
} ;
template <typename T>
class ClassA : public AbstractClass<T> {
    public:
        ClassA<T> operator[](int index){
            ClassA<T> A;
            return A;
        }
} ;
template <typename T>
class ClassB : public ClassA<T> {
    public:
        ClassA<T> operator[](int index){
            ClassA<T> A;
            return A;
        }
} ;
int main(void){
    ClassA<int> A;
    A[0][1][2];
}
```

Error:

```
test2.cpp(11): error: return type is neither identical to nor covariant with return type "AbstractClass<int>" of overridden virtual function "AbstractClass<T>::operator[] [with T=int]"
          ClassA<T> operator[](int index){
```

Changing to reference gives the warning of returning a local variable:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class AbstractClass {
    public:
        virtual AbstractClass<T>& operator[](int index) = 0;
} ;
template <typename T>
class ClassA : public AbstractClass<T> {
    public:
        ClassA<T>& operator[](int index){
            ClassA<T> A;
            return A;
        }
} ;
template <typename T>
class ClassB : public ClassA<T> {
    public:
        ClassA<T>& operator[](int index){
            ClassA<T> A;
            return A;
        }
} ;
int main(void){
    ClassA<int> A;
    A[0][1][2];
}
```

Warning

```
test2.cpp(13): warning #879: returning reference to local variable
              return A;
                     ^
          detected during instantiation of "ClassA<T> &ClassA<T>::operator[](int) [with T=int]" at line 26
```

And, I don't know to return a new object if I return by reference.

Some people suggested I can implement a move constructor.
But, I found that move constructor and template don't work together:
[Move operator with templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028929/move-operator-with-templates?rq=1)

Is there a solution?

Comment: before down vote. tell what is wrong in the code/the question. I will try to fix.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message actually?

Comment: Why the method of class A cannot return class A despite the abstract class says the method can return the abstract class, and class A is derived from the abstract class? Or what is the solution to make the methods of classA and classB to return classA?

Comment: That's not how polymorphism works in C++, you either have to use a reference or pointer to take advantage of polymorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning an `AbstractClass<T>` as an instance (not a reference or a pointer) requires the construction of a copy of this exact type. This is impossible for an abstract class.

To implement polymorphism, allocate an instance of the appropriate subclass on the head and return a pointer or a smart pointer like `std::shared_ptr` typed with the base class.

Comment: that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have two things wrong here:

1. When you return an `Base` as an instance, for the derived classes, you need the same type `Base` to be constructed.
2. When you write things like `ClassA A`, you don't specify the template arguments. It should really be:

   ```
   ClassA<T> A;
   ```

Comment: I changed to that. the local variable problem is still there, when I try to return by reference. Thanks for pointing out that mistake.

Comment: You either need a pointer, or a move constructor, so to transfer ownership

Comment: Do NOT return a pointer or a reference to a local variable on the stack! It will be invalid after the return of the method. You need to allocate an object on the heap, and return a (smart) pointer to it.

Comment: @ThomasBPreusser That isn't what I meant. This is what I meant: `return new ClassA<T>;` and yes, you will have to free the object explicitly returned. Of Course, if you had smart pointers or move constructors, that would be unnecessary.

Comment: Template and move constructor don't mix.

Comment: Why Not, it is still a class. In fact, one has already been auto-generated for you

Comment: I see that at the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028929/move-operator-with-templates?rq=1

Comment: You've interpreted the answer wrong, it still is allowed, just not in the expected way