# Template Move Constructor

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class

I want the derived ClassA to have a method that returns a brand new object of ClassA. I get compiler warning about returning reference to a local object.

Some people suggested I need to implement a move constructor. How to do that?

Code that doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class AbstractClass {
    public:
        virtual AbstractClass<T>& operator[](int index) = 0;
} ;
template <typename T>
class ClassA : public AbstractClass<T> {
    public:
        ClassA<T>& operator[](int index){
            ClassA<T> A;
            return A;
        }
        ClassA(ClassA && c){
            //move constructor that doesn't work.
        }
} ;
template <typename T>
class ClassB : public ClassA<T> {
    public:
        ClassA<T>& operator[](int index){
            ClassA<T> A;
            return A;
        }
} ;
int main(void){
    ClassA<int> A;
    A[0][1][2];
}
```

Error message (intel icc):

```
test2.cpp(15): error: copy constructor for class "ClassA<T>" may not have a parameter of type "ClassA<T>"
          ClassA(ClassA && c){
                 ^
```

Another version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class AbstractClass {
    public:
        virtual AbstractClass<T> operator[](int index) = 0;
} ;
template <typename T>
class ClassA : public AbstractClass<T> {
    public:
        ClassA<T>() {}
        ClassA<T> operator[](int index){
            ClassA<T> A;
            return A;
        }
} ;
template <typename T>
class ClassB : public ClassA<T> {
    public:
        ClassA<T> operator[](int index){
            ClassA<T> A;
            return A;
        }
} ;
int main(void){
    ClassA<int> A;
    A[0][1][2];
}
```

Error (intel icc):

```
test2.cpp(12): error: return type is neither identical to nor covariant with return type "AbstractClass<int>" of overridden virtual function "AbstractClass<T>::operator[] [with T=int]"
          ClassA<T> operator[](int index){
                    ^
          detected during instantiation of class "ClassA<T> [with T=int]" at line 26

test2.cpp(26): error: object of abstract class type "ClassA<int>" is not allowed:
            pure virtual function "AbstractClass<T>::operator[] [with T=int]" has no overrider
      ClassA<int> A;
                  ^

test2.cpp(12): error: function returning abstract class "ClassA<int>" is not allowed:
            pure virtual function "AbstractClass<T>::operator[] [with T=int]" has no overrider
          ClassA<T> operator[](int index){
                    ^
          detected during instantiation of "ClassA<T> ClassA<T>::operator[](int) [with T=int]" at line 27

test2.cpp(13): error: object of abstract class type "ClassA<int>" is not allowed:
            pure virtual function "AbstractClass<T>::operator[] [with T=int]" has no overrider
              ClassA<T> A;
                        ^
          detected during instantiation of "ClassA<T> ClassA<T>::operator[](int) [with T=int]" at line 27

compilation aborted for test2.cpp (code 2)
```

Comment: I looked it up in stack overflow and google. some pages mentioned move constructor, but not many pages talk about template move constructor. if i know why it doesn't work, i wouldn't ask.

Comment: Add the compiler you're using in your question

Comment: intel icc. well. i just found "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028929/move-operator-with-templates?rq=1" So the "solution" they suggested actually won't work.

Comment: What should `operator[]` do? Did you mean to return `*this`? Please, compile with C++11 standard. And you need to declare `ClassA() = default;` alongside the move constructor.

Comment: you need to be sure of what you are doing when you mix polymorphism and templates. Even as an example this code looks over-engineered.

Comment: the compiler is old, and fixing that is not realistic because the computer is a cluster, and i don't own the cluster.

Comment: @UmNyobe it is for doing something like numpy library of python. that library is very popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you have an error in the following part:

```
ClassA<T>& operator[](int index){
            ClassA<T> A; // <-- this variable will be destroyed
            return A; // and you return a reference to A
        }
```

The return value is a reference to the temporal variable `A` which will be destroyed after operator `[]` execution.

I suggest you to fix this error before all.

In addition, you do not have any constructor that initializes the class.

Putting some constructor that initializes, some such as

```
ClassA<T>() {}
```

compiles with `gnu` and `clang`

[Un demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5479eb0319558603)

Comment: that is the thing to fix. how to fix it? Some people says move constructor. some says return a pointer. The 1st solution won't work with template. The 2nd one seems bad.

Comment: That depends on from what do you want to do. If the idea is to return a copy of an object then remove the `&` qualifier first

Comment: removing & won't work with the abstract class... can't return an abstract class.

Comment: `ClassA` is not an abstract class. The abstract class is `AbstractClass`. Anyway, I edited my answer and put a dummy constructor that initializes the   state. After that, I achieve to compile with `gnu` and `clang`

Comment: can you add the full code? I tried and put the new code in the question.

Comment: Done @rxu. Look at the answer and review the demo

Comment: the demo actually doesn't use any of the classes. it will compile, but that doesn't show that the classes can be used.

Comment: Of course. The idea was to show you that compiles. The warning is exactly what I said you at the beginning of my answer

Comment: then that doesn't fix the problem. upvoted for the effort.

Comment: Well. I don't know what are you expecting. You have reported a compilation problem and I showed you how to fix it. Anyway, this thread is not becoming productive. Try to be more grateful for the time of others. I hope you solve your problem. Good luck